# Dapper ORM and Paging and Sorting Extension

Tags: dapper

I am using Dapper for a Generic DAL that can be used for both Oracle and SQL server. What would be the best way to provide Paging and Sorting methods so that it works both for SQL and Oracle without manually creating/changing the SQL statments?
Something like:

```
var users= Dapper
           .Query<User>(sqlStatment
                        .Skip(10)
                        .Take(10)); // where sqlStatment string
```

Comment: I don't know if you're doing yourself a favor with a generic method. Oracle has ROWNUM while SQL Server has TOP / ROW_NUMBER(). I'd implement a specification for each of the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Alex pointed out, paging is done differently on the two databases of your choice so your best best for having most optimized queries is to write separate queries for each.

It would probably be best to create two data provider assemblies each one serving each database:

- Data.Provider.Sql
- Data.Provider.Oracle

And then configure your application for one of the two. I've deliberately also created `Data.Provider` namespace (which can be part of some **Data** assembly and defines all data provider interfaces (within `Data.Provider`) that upper couple of providers implement.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I will probably create different SQL statements for each type and still use the same classes/methods.

Comment: @Shuaib: I suggest you rather use interfaces as suggested because this will make your code easily testable via IoC. And always refer to these interfaces when using them in upper layers. Your interfaces should define all methods you need to accomplish your data process requirement.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Can you give me a bit of details about the architectural design of this approach?

Comment: @RobertKoritnik any source code for your implementation?

Comment: @Smith no. Isn't my answer clear? And according to the post there isn't any actual code possible, because they're talking about paging of *any* result set. I merely advised them to create three namespaces: `Data.Provider`, `Data.Provider.Sql` and `Data.Provider.Oracle`. The first one should define all types (interfaces and abstract classes) that the latter couple of namespaces would implement each on top of their specific data store.